# How to use the Google Tag Manager API to create Google Analytics 4 tags?

Tags: google-analytics, google-api, google-tag-manager, google-analytics-4

Looking at the GTM documentation, specifically the [Tag Dictionary](https://developers.google.com/tag-platform/tag-manager/api/v2/tag-dictionary-reference#analytics), there appears to be references for *Universal Analytics* and even *Classical Analytics* - but it doesn't mention GA4 anywhere.

1. Is it therefore not currently possible to create GA4 tags, triggers, etc.
   through the Tag Manager API?
2. If it's not possible, are there any alternative ways to automate the creation of GA4 tags?

Answer (score 0):

I should have done a bit more digging before posting this question.

While it's not mentioned in the documentation, there *are* in fact tag types for GA4 - Configuration is `gaawc` and the Event tag is `gaawe`.